# Does it make sense to close a file that couldn't be opened

Tags: php, file, fopen

I'm reviewing code that was written by another developer. The code tries to open a file, and sets `$canOpen` based on success/failure.

```
$fh = @fopen('files.php', 'a+');        
if (!$fh){
   fclose($fh);
   $canOpen = false;
} else {
   $canOpen = true; 
}
```

What I find strange is that it also tries to close the file but only when the open fails `if (!$fh)`. Does this make sense? Shouldn't the close be in the else statement when the file was successfully opened?

Comment: yes that would be my assumption.  My guess is the way it is now would give an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it makes no sense.

If `!$fh` is met as a condition, it means the `$fh` contains boolean `FALSE` (or possibly, in the event of some weird internal PHP error, `NULL`). So what you are effectively doing is:

```
fclose(FALSE);
```

...which is pointless and will result in an error.

And, if all you're trying to do is populate the `$canOpen` variable and not do anything useful with the file handle, wouldn't a combination of [`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php), [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) and [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writeable.php) suffice?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason one would close an unopened file is if it is for resiliency purposes. For example, always closing the file in the `finally` block of a `try...catch`.

In your case, it looks like a coding error.

Answer (score 1):

if you put a var_dump( $fh ) in the true block of your if, you'll find that it's not a resource handle.

The [php manual states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) that fclose takes a resource.  Therefore fclose can't be called on a file that can't be  opened.

```
<?php
$fh = @fopen('files.php', 'a+');

if (!$fh){
    var_dump( $fh );
    fclose($fh); // this will cause an error
    $canOpen = false;
} else {
    $canOpen = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't make sense, if you cannot open the file you won't need to close it eigther. At this point the filepointer is always open because if the file doesn't exists it will create a file.